# Where are dimensions of load balancer metrics within log analytics

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-load-balancer

I'm trying to build a Kusto query based on dimension attributes of the DipAvailability metric for a load balancer in log analytics.  Documentation states they are ProtocolType, BackendPort, FrontendIPAddress, FrontendPort, BackendIPAddress, but I cannot see them anywhere in the DipAvailability metric data.

UPDATE: Screenshot of where I'm trying to grab the multi-dimensional data.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log analytics currently works only for **public Basic load balancers**. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log).

Azure Standard load balancer provides new multi-dimensional diagnostic capabilities through Azure Monitor for both public and internal load balancer configurations. You can view these [load balancer metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-diagnostics#a-name--multidimensionalmetricsamulti-dimensional-metrics) via the metric page on the Azure portal. You also could retrieve multi-dimensional metric definitions and values, see [Azure Monitoring REST API walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-rest-api-walkthrough).

### Update

You can view these multi-dimensional metrics through Azure Monitor for standard Load Balancer. **Add Filter** to select ProtocolType, BackendPort, FrontendIPAddress, FrontendPort, BackendIPAddress. Also note that

> Sending multi-dimensional metrics via diagnostic settings is not
>   currently supported. Metrics with dimensions are exported as flattened
>   single dimensional metrics, aggregated across dimension values.

Refer to [Supported metrics with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics).

[image]

Comment: Understood, but my question really relates to where the multi-dimensional metric attributes are stored in the log analytics.  Unless I'm misunderstanding you, they should be there but I don't see them in the AzureMetrics table.

Comment: What's the SKU of load balancer? If you think it should be stored in the log analytics, can you also find it in the linked storage account if you enable it to store in the storage account? I just see the DipAvailability metric for a standard load balancer in the metrics page in the Azure portal.

Comment: SKU is standard.  I can see high level metrics but not dimensions.  Are you saying that only the basic load balancer stores dimensions in log analytics?

Comment: Per that linked doc, only public basic SKU provides diagnostic logs  through Azure Log Analytics diagnostic logs. You can view multi-dimensional diagnostic  in Standard SKU. Check my update。

Comment: I understand that I can view these metrics via the metrics of the load balancer.  I've always been able to do that.  The question relates to where multi-dimensional values stored in log analytics schema so I can query them at the probe grain.  I can see metrics in the AzureMetrics table, but I cannot see where I can write the query to restrict based on the muti-dimensional attributes such as a specific health probe or rule like I can when looking at the metrics on the load balancer itself (see updated picture above)

Comment: I understood. As my reply updated before, `Sending multi-dimensional metrics via diagnostic settings is not currently supported. Metrics with dimensions are exported as flattened single dimensional metrics, aggregated across dimension values.` so the dimensions on the DipAvailability metric are not sent on to Log Analytics. Also, I confirm with this in [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/20916).